# PHP include with varying URI structure

Tags: php, include, directory

I am using a `.htaccess` file to rewrite all URI addresses to take the user to `index.php` where some code determines which file to include based on the URL.

If the URL however is in a subfolder from that of the header the include function is not fetching the file.

eg.

`index.php` includes a file located at `examplefolder/content/page.php`. That file then includes a header on the content page but `include('../header.php');` is not working. The URL is `example.com/news/latest`.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`chdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) function to change the current working directory on the webserver to get your relative paths to work correctly.

To see what the current working directory is, just `echo getcwd();`  Once you do that, you may realize that you don't need your relative paths and you can just structure the include based off of whatever your current working directory is (if you're rewriting to index.php, then all of your pages will start from the same base path, namely the web root).

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite all URLs to `/index.php`, all requests will be working from the `/` directory (i.e. document root).

So if you are including `examplefolder/content/page.php` and from there you want to include the file `examplefolder/header.php`, then that is exactly what you would write, because including a file does not change the working directory in the current thread of execution.

E.g.

```
include('examplefolder/header.php');
```